# JQuery Form Validator Plugin & Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using this [JQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/) and a newbie in Ajax. The validation works fine but my problem is it will still send the form even though there are errors.

---

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" onsubmit="return submitdata();">
    <p><input type="text" id="v_name" placeholder="Enter name here..." data-validation="required"></p>
    <p><input type="email" id="v_email" class="email" placeholder="Enter email here..." data-validation="email"></p>
    <p><textarea id="v_message" placeholder="Enter message here..." data-validation="required"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<p id="success"></p>

<script>
$.validate({
form : '#contactForm' // initiliaze form validation
});


function submitdata()
    {
     var name    = $("#v_name").val();
     var email   = $("#v_email").val();
     var message = $("#v_message").val();

         $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'functions.php',
          data: {
           post_name    : name,
           post_email   : email,
           post_message : message
          },
          success: function (response) {
           $('#success').html("Thanks! I will get in touch with you soon.");
           $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
          }
     });    

        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please indulge my brevity:

- Remove the `onsubmit="return submitdata()"` attribute. Instead, hook into the Validation API (see below).
- The `$.validate({})` method has a configuration property called `onSuccess` which accepts a function. Either assign the `submitdata` function to this property or assign it an anonymous function and call the `submitdata()` function in it.

Please see this fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/uwx40zq7/#&togetherjs=F7NqwDLRmp.

Please see this link for the configuration options for jQuery Form Validation http://www.formvalidator.net/#configuration.

You were close to getting it right. The problem is that you added the `onSubmit` attribute to the form and also validated the form with `$.validate()` at the same time. They weren't connected together, and so had no way of knowing about each other. By using the `onSuccess` property of the `$.validate()` configuration, you're hooking your submit function into the validation API and telling it to only use the `submitdata()` function if there are no validate errors.

Please let me know if I need to explain it better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that did it and was easy to understand.